# How can a person who can't read Hebrew be yotzeh the megillah?

Tags: halacha, purim, megillat-esther

Jews are obligated to hear the reading of the megillah during the night and day of Purim.

For someone who doesn't know how to read Hebrew, what should he do while sitting in shul and listening to the bal koreh in order to fulfill his obligation?

Comment: Just that, listen and one will be yotzeh

Comment: Is it okay to read the English translation while hearing the recitation?

Comment: @AniYodea related in a way http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55976/is-a-video-simulcast-megilla-reading-for-the-hearing-impaired-in-shul-permissi

Comment: @AniYodea https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120344/759

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A person fulfills his obligation by hearing the megillah read in the original Hebrew even if he does not understand the meaning of the words ([*Shulchan Aruch* OC 690:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97)).

In fact, even the rabbis of the Talmud were not certain of the translation of some words in [*Esther* 8:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3308.htm#10) (see [*M'gilla* 18a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=18&format=text), [*Mishna B'rura* 690:26](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97)).