# On Purim, is it permitted to read an English translation while listening to the Megillah reading?

Tags: purim, translation, megillat-esther, kavana-concentration

On Purim, is it permitted to read an English translation while listening to the Megillah reading?

I know it is a mitzvah to listen to every word of the Megillah reading. However, I don't understand Hebrew, so even if I listen, I barely understand anything.

If I "listen" (I hear the words being said) but at the same time I am reading an English translation, so as to actually understand the Megillah, is this permitted?

Comment: Even those who speak Hebrew well don't understand it all fwiw.

Comment: Some of the answers seem to be assuming that you mean, reading it _out loud_. Probably not a good idea. But if you mean, following with your eyes during the reading, keeping up, I think it's a great idea and often do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**On Purim, is it permitted to read an English translation while listening to the Megillah read in Hebrew?**

- Yes. - If the reader of the English translation is silent while listening to the Megillah read in Hebrew by a minyan (heard in person, not over microphone or telephone). [https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Reading_the_Megillah]

Understanding המגילה is the reward, while listening to המגילה simply fulfills the obligation.

**[Hilkhot Megillah 2:3](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3a02.htm)**

> "A foreigner who heard the Megillah written in the Hebrew language and the Hebrew alphabet--even though he doesn't know what they are saying, he fulfills his obligation." ( הלועז ששמע את המגילה הכתובה בלשון הקודש, ובכתב הקודש--אף על פי שאינו יודע מה הן אומרין, יצא ידי חובתו )

Answer (score -1):

[This responsum](https://library.yctorah.org/lindenbaum/reading-the-megillah-in-english/) from Rabbi Meir Ben Zion Hai Uziel, Sephardic Chief Rabbi when Israel was founded, concludes as follows:

> A man who does not know Hebrew who hears the megillah read in Hebrew to others who speak Hebrew fulfills his obligation; but if the megillah is read just to him, we must read it to him in the vernacular and not in Hebrew.

A fortiori, this implies it's OK for him to read the English while he hears the Hebrew.

Comment: He must read his vernacular out of a kosher scroll though.

Comment: Your link says explicitly "Unlike a Torah scroll, Jewish law permits a megillah to be written in translation."

Comment: What, then, is a "kosher" scroll?

Comment: Processed animal hide, black ink, line scoring, sinew sewing, Jewish scribe, dominant hand, writing not etching, etc.

Comment: http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=or_6287_fs001r Megillah written in spanish (h/t magicker72)

Comment: Here's a recent [English-language megillah](https://www.facebook.com/YCTorah/posts/10160055295878274) using Robert Alter's translation. (@DoubleAA you might enjoy too.)